# SQL how can i select data between dates?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables

**EVENTS**

```
EventCode    EventDate
1            2013-07-22 04:00:00.000
2            2013-07-21 11:00:00.000
3            2013-07-21 10:00:00.000
```

**DeviceSignal** which is transaction table

```
TimeStamp                   DeviceID    Value
2013-07-22 03:10:00.000     Dev1             33
2013-07-22 03:00:00.000     Dev2             22
2013-07-21 11:00:00.000     Dev3             23
2013-07-21 10:50:00.000     Dev4             45
2013-07-21 10:40:00.000     Dev5             23
2013-07-21 10:30:00.000     Dev1             54
2013-07-21 10:20:00.000     Dev2             22
2013-07-21 09:50:00.000     Dev1             11
2013-07-21 09:40:00.000     Dev2             23
```

Base on the EventDate , i would like to get timestamp , deviceID and Value, TimeStamp is in the EventDate Hierarchy , how can i get below output ?

```
EventCode   EventDate               TimeStamp               DeviceID    Value
1           2013-07-22 04:00:00.000 2013-07-22 03:10:00.000  Dev1       33
1           2013-07-22 04:00:00.000 2013-07-22 03:00:00.000  Dev2       22
2           2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 2013-07-21 10:50:00.000  Dev4       45
2           2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 2013-07-21 10:40:00.000  Dev5       23
2           2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 2013-07-21 10:30:00.000  Dev1       54
2           2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 2013-07-21 10:20:00.000  Dev2       22
3           2013-07-21 10:00:00.000 2013-07-21 09:50:00.000  Dev1       11
3           2013-07-21 10:00:00.000 2013-07-21 09:40:00.000  Dev2       23
```

Comment: What happened to the `2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 , Dev3 , 23` row?

Comment: Can you provided details of the "EventDate Hierarchy" that you mention?

Comment: And the first 2 rows in `DeviceSignal` have 21st of July while the results have 22nd. Is that a typo or something peculiar needs to be done with the datetimes?

Comment: thank you very much ypercube , first two rows is typo, will edit . now i am applying your sql code in my application data .

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    e.EventCode, e.EventDate,
    d.TimeStamp, d.DeviceID, d.Value
FROM 
    DeviceSignal AS d
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) e.EventCode, e.EventDate
      FROM Events AS e
      WHERE d.TimeStamp <= e.EventDate
      ORDER BY e.EventDate
    ) AS e ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    EV.EventCode, 
    EV.EventDate,
    DS.Timestamp,
    DS.DeviceID,
    DS.Value
FROM
    Events EV JOIN DeviceSignal DS 
        ON CAST(EV.EventDate AS DATE) = CAST(DS.TimeStamp AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EV.[EventCode],EV.[EventDate],DS.[TimeStamp],DS.DeviceID,DS.[Value] 
from [Events] EV INNER JOIN [DeviceSignal] DS
on CONVERT(DATE,ev.EventDate)=CONVERT(DATE,DS.[TimeStamp])
```